# How do I setup p4.el on emacs?

Tags: emacs, perforce

I tried the basic setup as given in the sourceforge page and set
P4CONFIG, P4USER, P4PORT.
and after opening emacs I load p4.el and try to set the client name
using p4-set-client-name and it throws out this error:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
Can't create a new user - over license quota.
License count: 1000 users used of 1000 licensed.
Try deleting old users with 'user -d'.
```

But when I try opening it using p4v it opens up just fine.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `(getenv "P4USER")` when executed in emacs matches the value of `echo $P4USER` in your shell?

Answer (score 2):

I'd make sure that your P4USER environment variable is set properly in your emacs process (M-x getenv).  For sure, it looks like p4 procs spawned from your emacs are using an incorrect P4USER.

Also note that on Windows, you can "p4 set P4USER=username" rather than using an environment variable; this will take effect right away.